# Can Eclipse add method description on {+enter

Tags: eclipse

How can I have Eclipse to automatically add method description block on method definition?

If I write: `public int test(int hello){`

And then press "Enter".
The Eclipse will add the end bracket two lines below, so the code ends up like this:

```
public int test(int hello){

}
```

If I then press ctrl+shift+j while the cursor is in the method name, the code ends up like this:

```
/**
 * @param hello
 * @return
 */
public int test(int hello){

}
```

**Now my question is**: *Is it possible to let Eclipse add the method description (what is added on ctrl+shift+j) automatically, when I create the method? At the same time as it creates the end bracket*.

Answer (score 0):

What you have mentioned as method description is technically known as Javadoc comment. In Eclipse - Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Keys has the list of command and the keys binding to those commands. You can change the keys as per your comfort.

Comment: But, what I want is the Javadoc to be added on method creation. Just like the end bracket is created.

Comment: Did you try to change the key for 'Add Javadoc comment' command to Enter key? Didn't it work?

Comment: Yes, then you cannot get a new line when pressing enter.